# Constrain size of existing text object?

Tags: inkscape, text

If I switch to the text tool and just click in one spot, without dragging out an area, it normally appears as a text object which does not have a constrained size.

Another method which sometimes results in the same is if copying text from another source and pasting into Inkscape.

One effect of this is that you can't get automatic linebreaks (you have to use [Enter]).

Is there some way to 'convert' this text object so that its size can be constrained?

Example, I want to convert this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try this: copy the text, then create a flowed text box with the text tool (by clicking and dragging), and then paste the copied text into it.

Comment: @BillyKerr sure that will work... but is inconvenient if you have a lot of these. That's why I'm looking for a way to alter it from one to the other (if that is even possible)

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way to convert it, at least not as a standard function in Inkscape. However perhaps you could program (or find) an extension to automate it, but coding is way beyond my abilities unfortunately. Also, probably the best idea is to make sure you are pasting from your source into a flowed text box, then you can avoid this situation happening in the first place.

Comment: Another possibility is a workaround - using [flow into frame](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Flow.html), although it's not quite the same as a flowed text box, it might work for you.

Answer (score 4):

With the Text tool (T) selected and the text you wanna place in clipboard, click and drag to make a Flow Text box and Ctrl+V to paste the text.

[image: Image showing how to add flowed text in Inkscape.]

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. But I am hoping to find a way to convert an existing single-line text object to the "flowed" type, not just make a new one.

Comment: @DaveInCaz, there is no such way in Inkscape currently. The next version might allow it (I've seen and used that feature already).

Comment: @Moini thank you. I guess you could post that as an answer then update it in the future if you want?

Comment: @DaveInCaz The feature isn't entirely ready yet, I would possibly describe it incorrectly if I did it now.